# How to insert a text in List using linq

Tags: c#, linq, file

I am very new to linq programining in c# and I have below text file and read the file and stored in
List

IP/ Text file
DC List:

```
North: &North
**arr prod_test**
Dcname BN14

south: &south
**arr prod_test**
Dcname BN1

East: &East
**arr ff_test**
DcName RD1

NorthEast: &NorthEast
**arr mc_test**
DcName RR

WestEast: &NorthEast
**arr mc_test**
DcName RR
```

O/p file:

DC List:

```
North: &North
**arr prod_test**
Dcname BN14

south: &south
**arr prod_test**
Dcname BN1

East: &East
**arr ff_test**
DcName RD1

/// here I need to add the new text my doubt is how to find the  insert position and how to add the content using linq query 
West: &West
**arr ff_test**
DcName RD1

NorthEast: &NorthEast
**arr mc_test**
DcName RR

WestEast: &NorthEast
**arr mc_test**
DcName RR
```

I need to search for arr_ff_test and need to insert the next content before  East: &East,
Please help me in this using linq.

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(buildOutFile).ToList();
index = lines.FindIndex(element => element.Contains("arr ff_test"));
temp = String.Format($"West: &West\n    **arr ff_test**\nDcName RD1);
lines.Insert(index-1, temp);
```

I want to change above three lines to linq

Comment: Please show an actual code sample that creates the list with sample data, as well as the object that contains the data to be inserted. It's not clear if this is a list of strings, but it seems like a good candidate for a list of objects that each have 3 string properties.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do with the text, since it seems to me that your approach is wrong in the first place. What text do you want to insert (Is it specifically the same text as in temp, or does it change according to North/South etc.)? Where do you want to insert it(in the variable `lines`, or elsewhere? If you want to use LINQ, do you want to make this insertion only once (as you wrote in your 3 lines of code), or at every occurance of the 'arr_ff_test'? Also, why you wish to do this by LINQ and not by Regex?

Comment: I need to add temp text in lines and that lines will further write into text file, temp data will varies based on input

Comment: @Sravani Okay, so in the end, you want to change the file itself, and wherever you encounter the "arr_ff_test" line, you wish to add an additional line before it, right? Instead of reading file, storing lines in array, and then using LINQ on it, it would be better to use a textstream to read your input file line by line, and another text stream to write your output file line by line and also adds the additional line you want. Will that answer work for you?

Comment: In general, I would not advise to use LINQ here, because here you want to iterate through the `lines` variable, and also changing it while iterating. This is bad design and will create more bugs in your logic. Morever, you wish to change/edit that part of the line which is not being iterated, but the element before it. So I don't think you should use LINQ here.

Comment: yes , you are correct instead of list<string> you are suggesting text stream .my question is how to figure out the position where I need to add the text and how to add the text using Linq

Comment: Have you read the documentation for C#/.Net? You can use [`List<T>.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-7.0) to find a position, then use [`List<T>.InsertRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insertrange?view=net-7.0) to insert a collection of lines before the found element.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to use streams here. You should not  read the lines in an array, then use LINQ to do what you want, since this action of iterating a collection and modifying it is bad design.

Here is a sample code that I tested. I added comments to explain my code as well.

```cs
public void ReadText()
{
    // Stream for the existing file "sample.txt"
    using (StreamReader input = new StreamReader(new FileStream("sample.txt", FileMode.Open)))
    {
        // Stream for output file that is to be created or overwritten
        using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("output.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
        {
            // We need to look ahead two lines at a time
            string second_line, first_line;
            first_line = input.ReadLine();

            // This loop goes on for every line in the input file
            while ((second_line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (second_line.Contains("arr ff_test")) // This is the line where the insertions are to be made
                {
                    // Now insert the extra lines you want in your output file
                    output.WriteLine("West: &West");
                    output.WriteLine("**arr ff_test**");
                    output.WriteLine("DcName RD1");
                    output.WriteLine(); // Make an empty line
                }
                output.WriteLine(first_line); // write the same line in output as it is
                first_line = second_line; // the first line is moved foreward
            }
            output.Write(first_line); // The last line is yet to be written

            // Close both the files
            output.Close();
        }
        input.Close();
    }
}
```

The trick here is to look ahead two lines at a time. I tested it with your given input and output files and seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the position of the entries counts somehow, I understand that you need to insert the block referring to West after the East part. That is to say before the NorthEast one, correct?
In that case it seems easier that you look for NorthEast instead and insert preceding than to look for East and insert after.

in that case the code becomes:

```
private List<string> Merge2(string buildOutFile)
{
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(buildOutFile).ToArray();
var textToInsert = new List<string>()
{
    "West: &West",
    "**arr ff_test**",
    "DcName RD1"
}.ToArray();
var oneLineSource = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
var oneLineinsertion = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, textToInsert);
var separator = "NorthEast: &NorthEast";
var twoParts = oneLineSource.Split(separator);
string onelinerOutput = twoParts[0] + oneLineinsertion + twoParts[1];
return onelinerOutput.Split().ToList();
}
```

If you want to use linq at every cost:

```
private List<string> Merge(string buildOutFile)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(buildOutFile);
    var separator = "NorthEast: &NorthEast";
    var textToInsert = $"{separator}{Environment.NewLine}West: &West{Environment.NewLine}**arr ff_test**{Environment.NewLine}DcName RD1{ Environment.NewLine}"; 
    return lines.Select(line=>line.Contains(separator)?textToInsert:line).ToList();                    
}
```

In case your additional text is not hardcoded you can simply put other placeholders in the separator interpolated string to get it customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input file is uniformly composed of blocks of 3 lines each followed by an empty line, you only need the line index of that 'arr ff_test' entry and calculate the next follwing multiple of 4.
There insert your additional lines. And you're done.
The 'Q' in 'LinQ' indicates it's most powerful for querying lists. Wouldn't recommend it for insertion of text. `List<string>` is the tool with everything necessary already built-in.

```
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputFilePath).ToList();
    var matchPos = lines.IndexOf("**arr ff_test**");
    if (matchPos > -1)  {
        // get next multiple of 4 as insertion index ...
        var insertPos = ((matchPos / 4) + 1) * 4; 
        lines.InsertRange(insertPos, new[] {
            "West: &West", "**arr ff_test**", "DcName RD1", ""});
        File.WriteAllLines(outputFilePath, lines.ToArray());
    }
```